# Conditional Relay trigger

Tags: relay

I want to design a circuit to trigger a relay depending on the house current load:
When current load is below 12A the relay must turn on and when current load goes above 17A relay must turn off.
How can this be done knowing that the relay will switch a 4A 220Volt heater.

thank you

Comment: First think how you are going to detect the load..

Comment: Does this circuit disconnect the load that you are measuring? If so, what happens when the load is disconnected and the current drops to zero? In other words, how do you stop the circuit from oscillating?

Comment: @Dwayne : as the hysteresis is comfortably more than the switched load, this shouldn't oscillate. Of course if the load is increased above 5A...

Comment: No the circuit will not disconnect the load i am measuring..

Answer (score 1):

1. Get something that measures the current, and have it produce a voltage signal proportional to that current.

   Set up a comparator with hysteresis so that it goes to the on state when the current sense voltage indicates 12 A, and the off state when it indicates 17 A.

   Drive a 220 VAC 6 A relay from the comparator output.

Comment: This is exactly what i was thinking of doing but what can i use to measure the current and produce a voltage signal first second how  to design the comparator circuit?

Comment: a split-core current transformer (or current clamp as it is called).

Answer (score 1):

Monitor the utility meter. Some have a spinning disc, others have blinking LED.

[image: Photo detection of energy meter.]

*Energy meter photo sensor.*

**Analog option**

- Generate an analog voltage proportional to the pulse rate.
- Feed this into threshold comparitors and control your relay with some logic from those.

This will be a pain to set up.

**Digital option**

- Feed the signal into a micro and time the pulse interval.
- Set interval thresholds corresponding to your desired switch points.
- Control the relay using digital output from the micro.

**Digital option bonuses**

- Run a meter or line of LEDs to give live power consumption indicator. Good for making family aware of energy consumption.
- Log the readings for graphing. I used a Raspberry Pi for mine and uploaded the readings to my web server every minute. What I could remotely deduce regarding household activity from that one piece of information was scarey!

[image: Energy monitor charts]

*Figure 2. Energy monitor web page.*